# Is it possible to run applications compiled by Visual Studio 2008 on Linux?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to run applications compiled by Visual Studio 2008 on Linux? Is there plugin that can convert my project exe to a Linux runnable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no software that allows Visual Studio to generate non-Windows executables.

If it's a native executable (not .NET) you can try running it under [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) and see if that works. If it doesn't I'd guess the options are either to make it work with WINE or see if you can build it as a native Linux application. The latter will be rather painful if it's a GUI application, obviously, and I'd question if it is worth it. Porting a command line app might be doable but don't underestimate the work involved.

Answer (score 1):

if you use dot net there is a MONO library that enables running some dot net application on linux.
but it not fully compatible.
Otherwise you can do it, (maybe using silverlite you would...)

[Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: @Dani I am using mono library .. You are right its not fully compatible